AttributeError: Options field max_parallel_threads is not valid for this backend
I am working on migrating my code to the latest version of qiskit==1.0. Below is a part of my code:
    backend = BasicProvider().get_backend("basic_simulator")

    # How to define the number of processors that are used by simulator?
    backend.set_options(
        max_parallel_threads = 0,  # Use all CPU cores
        max_parallel_experiments = 0,  
        max_parallel_shots = 42,             
        statevector_parallel_threshold = 16  
    )

    job = backend.run(qc_combine, shots= shots_used)
    result = job.result()
    counts = result.get_counts(qc_combine)

Not sure how to put these options in the latest version of qiskit. I am presently getting an Error:
 File "/panfs/pfs.local/scratch/i2s/m9c693/BQS_study/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/providers/backend.py", line 601, in set_options
    raise AttributeError("Options field %s is not valid for this backend" % field)
AttributeError: Options field max_parallel_threads is not valid for this backend

Need help in resolving this issue.

If you want to use all your CPU cores, it's likely that you're interested in efficient simulation, which BasicProvider doesn't provide. You should probably use qiskit-aer to run your code! You can find a code example here.

Thank you @TristanNemoz for great help. qiskit-aer simulator works better.

Similarly, did that answer your question fully? Just to know if I can put it as an answer, since I wasn't sure it would solve your problem

Thank you @TristanNemoz. Yes, your solution i.e., using backend = AerSimulator() solves the problem and it also fast.

As mentioned in the comments, if your goal is to efficiently simulate a quantum computation, then you should use qiskit-aer, rather than BasicSimulator. Indeed, from the latter's docs:

Python implementation of a basic (non-efficient) quantum simulator.

Whereas qiskit-aer is designed for efficiency. Thus, you should rather use:
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator

backend = AerSimulator(method='statevector')

And then go on with your code as previously.

Thank you @TristanNemoz for great help. What I actually used was as below:
backend = AerSimulator()
   
    backend.set_options(       .............     )
pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(backend=backend, optimization_level=1)
    qc_combine = pm.run(qc_combine)
    job = backend.run(qc_combine, shots= shots_used)
    result = job.result()
    counts = result.get_counts(qc_combine)             I will surely test this also.
